# Unable to locate package postgresql-server-dev?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, postgresql

I am trying to install the following packcage postgresql-server-dev-9.5. Using

> sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5

Now, after I run this command I get this error:

> Unable to locate package postgresql-server-dev-9.5.
>
> Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-server-dev-9.5'.
>
> Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-server-dev-9.5'

How can I fix this? I use ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: If you really want to use this older version of Postgres (it is supported, but not the latest), install it from the Postgres APT repostiory, see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 has [PostgreSQL 10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgresql-10), so the correct package there is `postgresql-server-dev-10`:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-server-dev-10
```

To determine the major PostgreSQL version in a given release of Ubuntu, find the matching entries in [the `postgresql-common` page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgresql-common). Thus:

- 19.04 has PostgreSQL 11 (`postgresql-server-dev-11`)
- 18.04 and 18.10 have PostgreSQL 10 (`postgresql-server-dev-10`)
- 16.04 has PostgreSQL 9.5 (the second part of the version number is significant here; `postgresql-server-dev-9.5`)
- 14.04 has PostgreSQL 9.3 (`postgresql-server-dev-9.3`)
- 12.04 has PostgreSQL 9.1 (`postgresql-server-dev-9.1`)

Answer (score 2):

There's an extension build tool for multiple PostgreSQL versions if you are unsure what version to install.

Try:

```
$ apt install postgresql-server-dev-all
```

Comment: I checked it in my system: `apt show postgresql-server-dev-all|grep Depends`
Depends: make, postgresql-common (>= 117~), postgresql-server-dev-12

Comment: Yes - that's the point of it.  Without knowing you need postgresql-server-dev-12 you can install postgresql-server-dev-all and it will choose the correct one (which is  postgresql-server-dev-12 in your case).  Not sure if you downvoted my answer but I don't know why someone would downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client
```

Comment: While this may work to actually install the server and client it does not provide the libraries required to compile other software against postgresql.

There's a special package called 'postgresql-server-dev-all' that can be used if you aren't sure what version to install.